# What are the different types of binary relationship types?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I'm new to databases and while studying questions on it, I've come across one that I can't find the answer to. **Define the three different binary relationship types** that are common in relational database design. Provide one example for each relationship type. I have searched for it but can't seem to find it, I just keep running into cardinality and different relationships types i.e. unary etc. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: One-to-One, One-to-Many, and Many-to-Many ?

Comment: If you had searched for "three different binary relationship types" you would have found lots of answers, such as Max's reply.

Comment: I thought one to one, one to many and many to many were called cardinality of a relationship.

Comment: TRUE, FALSE, or IS NULL?